# How to pass parameters to exe in alternate shell rdp

Tags: c#, parameters, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

I'm creating an **.rdp** file (Remote Desktop Protocol), which will open a machine and open a program made by me in **.NET C#**, I can already do this, but I would need to pass **parameters** to this program, is there any way?

Commands I'm using in .rdp file:

```
full address:s: ip_machine
alternate shell:s:c:\MPT\Program.exe
```

In microsoft documentation I couldn't find anything:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not finding a solution. Apparently it is not possible to pass parameters through the command line, only if it were a RemoteApp, which is not the case, as this should run on old windows.

I wanted to use parameters to open Forms. But as it was not possible, I will create an .exe for each form, where in the .rdp file I will inform which one I want to open.